# Recursively deleting every second element in a list

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869984/how-to-delete-elements-of-a-circular-list-until-there-is-only-one-element-left-u) got me thinking.

If you have a list of length `n` and recursively delete every other element from the list until only one element remains, is there any relationship between the index of the last remaining item and `n`?

For example, with a list of length `100`:

> $[0, 1, 2, ..., 99]$
>
> $[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 
> 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]$
>
> $[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 
> 91, 95, 99]$
>
> $[7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55, 63, 71, 79, 87, 95]$
>
> $[15, 31, 47, 63, 79, 95]$
>
> $[31, 63, 95]$
>
> $[63]$

You get the 63rd index in the list.

But with a list of length 1000, you get 511. And with a list of length 10000, you get 8191.

I feel like there's something obvious but I'm missing it. What is mathematically being done here? Can we predict the index with `n`?

edit: a user posted the formula `math.pow(2, math.floor(math.log(n, 2))) - 1` but I'd definitely love some explanation here.

Comment: what happens if you write the numbers in the list in base 2 ?

Comment: You get a lot of numbers in base 2...$[0, 1, 10, 11 ... 1100011]$ what's your point?

Comment: Hehe .. sorry I did'nt mean that :P .. my point is every number that has a 0 in its binary representation is struck off !!

Comment: @user129017 that's interesting, why?

Comment: See in the first step .. you strike off the even numbers (numbers ending with zero in bin. rep) .. remaining odd numbers end with 1 in binary. but the numbers occuring in even positions in this new list are the ones which have 0 in the second last position .. continuing to the k-th step you strike off the elements with 0 in the (k+1)-th place in binary (because those occur in the even position of the list)

Comment: @user129017 now can this translate into the formula for finding the very last index?

Comment: i think its easier if you think about it this way - try using a list from 1 to 100 instead of 0 to 99 - the initial list contains all multiples of $2^0$, the next time $2^1$ etc. When does this stop? After the recursion has been run log base 2 of n times (rounded down). So the last element left in the list is simply $2^6 - 1$ (- 1 since we started at 1 when we should be starting at 0)

Comment: the number left in the very last is the one that does not have a 0 in its binary rep. that if $k$ is largest power of 2 that does not exceed the length of the list .. the number is $2^k - 1$

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an algo guy :( .. I wont be able to write a constructive algorithmic solution !! Happy to be of help anyway :)

Comment: @StevenLi That's a great explanation, you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will always end up getting $2^n-1$ where n is maximum integer such that $2^n<K$